# Do we have the following?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Suppose the following integrals
\begin{equation}
\int_t^T X_s \, ds\ \text{ and }\ \int_t^T Y_s \, ds
\end{equation} 
are well-defined, where $X_s$ and $Y_s$ are continuous stochastic process. Do we have $$E\left[\int_t^T X_s \,ds \times \int_t^T Y_s \, ds\right]=\int_t^T E[X_sY_s] \, ds$$ in general?

Comment: Forgive me for possibly being naive, but what in the world is $\mathbb{E}\left[\int\limits_{t}^{T}X_s \text{ and } \int\limits_{t}^{T}Y_s\right]$ supposed to mean?

Comment: @Gordon : You did an edit using \mbox{} where \text{} is appropriate.  I've seen lots of people here do that.  Is there some style manual on the web somewhere telling people to do that? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Thanks for pointing that out and nice to know this  feature. I get used to use \mbox{} as it is the Latex style I usually use to add normal text within a math environment.

Comment: @Gordon : \text{} rather than \mbox{} is standard in LaTeX.  The purpose of \mbox{} in LaTeX is to prevent line breaks.  And \mbox{} and \text{} yield different restults in some contexts. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Thanks. It is good to know this. I usually use \mbox both for text and for preventing line breaks. But \text{} appears more intuitive.

Comment: OP: Would you by any chance be enquiring about $$E\left(\int X_sdB_s\int Y_sdB_s\right),$$ with $B$ some standard Brownian motion? 'Cause this is not what the question says at the moment. (Unrelated: Worst title ever.)

Answer (score 1):

Note that
\begin{align*}
\int_t^T X_s\, ds \int_t^T Y_s \,ds = \int_t^T\int_t^T X_s Y_u \,ds \,du.
\end{align*}
Then, by assuming the Fubini,
\begin{align*}
E\left(\int_t^T X_s\, ds \int_t^T Y_s\, ds\right) = \int_t^T\int_t^T E\left( X_s Y_u\right)\, ds \,du,
\end{align*}
which is generally not equal to $\int_t^T E( X_s Y_s) \,ds$.